# Checking the data returned for empty data while using ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using the jQuery code below to search for an employee and once the 
employee exists, other fields in the table are returned.

I want to be able to send an alert to the user if the employee was not found.
How can I achieve that?

```
$(document).on("click", "#btnEmpNumber", function () {
    var getdata = $('#EmpNumber').val();
    var url = "@Url.Action("GetEmployeeInformation", "Home")";

    $.post(url, { 'objdata': getdata }, function (data) {
        if (data == undefined) {
            alert("Invalid Employee");
        }

        $('#mainYourinformation').html(data);
    });
});
```

```csharp
public ActionResult GetEmployeeInformation(string objdata)
{
    Customerproductdto objGetEmpData = null;
    try
    {
        objGetEmpData = _DataService.SearchEmplByNumber(objdata);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
    }

    return PartialView("_Empinformation", objGetEmpData);
}

public class Customerproductdto
{
    public string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string EmployeePhone { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeTitle { get; set; }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `SearchEmplByNumber` return `null` when the employee was not found, you can return a different result from your action method.

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeInformation(string objdata)
{
    Customerproductdto objGetEmpData = null;
    try
    {
        objGetEmpData = _DataService.SearchEmplByNumber(objdata);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
    }
    if(objGetEmpData!=null)
       return PartialView("_Empinformation", objGetEmpData);

    return Content("No information found for the employee");
}
```

If you want fancy html markup than the simply message, create a new partial view with those fancy markup and return that.

```
    if(objGetEmpData!=null)
       return PartialView("_Empinformation", objGetEmpData);

    return PartialView("NoDataFoundForEmployee");
```

Assuming you have a view called `NoDataFoundForEmployee.cshtml` in `~/Views/Shared` or `~/Views/Home/`

There is no need of the if condition in your `$.post` success callback as your action method will always return some response.

**EDIT :** As per the comment

> I am using toastr to return messages and thats what I want to stick to

In this case, you may always return a json response from your action method with the below structure

```
{ 
  status="found",
  message="some Message for the user",
  resultMarkup="somehtmlToDisplayToUser"
}
```

You can use the below helper method([took from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2759898/40521)) to convert your view result to a string

```
public string RenderRazorViewToString(string viewName, object model)
{
  ViewData.Model = model;
  using (var sw = new StringWriter())
  {
    var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(ControllerContext,
                                                             viewName);
    var viewContext = new ViewContext(ControllerContext, viewResult.View,
                                 ViewData, TempData, sw);
    viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, sw);
    viewResult.ViewEngine.ReleaseView(ControllerContext, viewResult.View);
    return sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  }
}
```

Now in your action method,

```
public ActionResult GetEmployeeInformation(string objdata)
{
    Customerproductdto objGetEmpData = null;
    try
    {
        objGetEmpData = _DataService.SearchEmplByNumber(objdata);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.Error(ex);
         return Json(new { status="error", message="System Error!" });
    }
    if(objGetEmpData!=null)
    {
        var h= RenderRazorViewToString("_Empinformation", objGetEmpData);
        return Json(new { status="found", resultMarkup = h });
    }
    return Json(new { status="notfound", message="Employee not found" });
}
```

Now in your $.post method's callback, check the json response's status property value and show the markup or messsage.

```
$.post(url, { 'objdata': getdata }, function (data) {
    if (data.status==="found") {
        $('#mainYourinformation').html(data.resultMarkup);
    }
    else
    {
       alert(data.message);
       // or call the toastr method here
      // toastr.error(data.message, 'Not found')
    }

});
```

Comment: I am using toastr to return messages and thats what I want to stick to. Thanks

Comment: I really dont want to create another partial view. I want the main form to still be on the page and alert displays " No information was found"

Answer (score 1):

Return the exception from controller and catch that exception in `catch` block of `$.post` method and show alert to the user.

```
   $.post(url, { 'objdata.....).catch (function (ex){ 
         alert (ex);   
     });
```